# jQuery duplicate the row and delete the same with the selected row

Tags: jquery

I have my markup like this

```
<div class="language-wrapper">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select class="form-control required" id="language-first" name="language-first" aria-required="true">
            <option value="EN">English</option>
            <option value="CS">Czech</option>
            <option value="HU">Hungarian</option>
        </select>                           
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select class="form-control required" id="language-second" name="language-second" aria-required="true">
            <option value="EN">English</option>
            <option value="CS">Czech</option>
            <option value="HU">Hungarian</option>
        </select>                           
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn add-new-row">Add New Row</button>
</div>
```

Here I want to duplicate the row(clone). So for that I made the jQuery like this

```
jQuery('.add-new-row').click(function() {
    jQuery('.language-wrapper').clone().insertAfter('.language-wrapper');

});
```

Now this is one cloning and duplicationg the row but multiple times means first time it duplicates `2 rows then 4 rows then 6 and on..`
But I want a simple way and that is I will click on Add New Row button and it will clone the last row and insert after the last row. Also there is another thing. There will be remove row button. which will remove the row in which row the remove button is placed. So can someone tell me how to do this? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: you can try to find `language-wrapper` and then his last `div` child (not as @mathf adviced) and clone it.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to clone the whole language-wrapper div? If you want to clone the col-md-6 div, you could use the last() selector. This will only clone the last element with this css class.

```
jQuery('.col-md-6:last').clone().insertAfter('.language-wrapper');
```

Comment: and when I change page style I need to rewrite script))

Comment: Yes, or you can add an additional class like .row-editable which you can reuse in your application instead of referring to .col-md-6

Comment: I want to clone the total language-wrapper div... so how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

if I where you I would place button somewhere out from language div :

```
<div class="language-wrapper">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select class="form-control required" id="language-first" name="language-first" aria-required="true">
            <option value="EN">English</option>
            <option value="CS">Czech</option>
            <option value="HU">Hungarian</option>
        </select>                           
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select class="form-control required" id="language-second" name="language-second" aria-required="true">
            <option value="EN">English</option>
            <option value="CS">Czech</option>
            <option value="HU">Hungarian</option>
        </select>                           
    </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn add-new-row">Add New Row</button>
```

and script

```
var parent = $('div.language-wrapper')
parent.find("div:last").clone(true).appentTo(parent);
```

if you want clone whole div make this

```
var element= $('div.language-wrapper').last();
element.clone(true).insertAfter(parent);
```

Answer (score 0):

misunderstood you request at first... here's the solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/8b23omfc/1/

```
$('.add-new-row').click(function() {
    $('.language-wrapper:last').clone(true).insertAfter('.language-wrapper:last');
    $(this).after('<button type="button" class="btn del-row">delete Row</button>');
    $(this).remove();
});

$('.language-wrapper').on('click','.del-row',function() {
 $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

on click, you clone the last language-wrapper. the 'true' inside the clone call would delegate the click handler to the cloned button.
next, we create a delete row button and append it into the current 'row'
in the end, we delete the add row button from the current row.

thus, you can have several language wrappers, delete them as you want but always keep at least one!